# Service account failed to get pods although it has permissions "Error from server (Forbidden): ..."

Tags: kubernetes, token

I created a service account and I want to give it permissions to list pods: `kubectl get pods`.

I have these settings for service account, role and rolebinding:

**ServiceAccount.yaml**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myservice3
```

**Role.yaml**:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  namespace: default
  name: my-role
rules: 
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

**RoleBinding.yaml**:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  name: my-role-binding
  namespace: default
subjects: 
- kind: ServiceAccount 
  name: myservice3
  namespace: default
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef: 
  kind: Role
  name: my-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

I created a user with the token of the service account:

```
SECRET_NAME=`kubectl get serviceaccounts myservice3 -o json | jq -r '.secrets[].name'`
TOKEN=`kubectl get secrets $SECRET_NAME -o json | jq -r '.data | .token' | base64 -d`
kubectl config set-credentials $USER_NAME --token=$TOKEN
```

Set a context to this user:

```
kubectl config set-context my-context \
--cluster=kubernetes \
--namespace=default \
--user=$USER_NAME
```

When tried to use its permissions:

```
$ kubectl get pods --context=my-context
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:myservice3" cannot list pods in the namespace "default"
```

I also tried with `curl`:

```
$ curl -k -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://127.0.0.1:6443
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 6443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 6443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=kube-apiserver
*       start date: Jul 02 09:36:21 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 02 09:36:21 2019 GMT
*       common name: kube-apiserver
*       issuer: CN=kubernetes
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:6443
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <JWT_token>
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2018 12:17:10 GMT
< Content-Length: 257
<
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:myservice3\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  I gave the service account a `get pods` permissions and it is still being forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Role.yaml needed to have also `list`:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  namespace: default
  name: my-role
rules: 
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

`get` is a permission to get an individual item and `list` is permission to get all itmes.
Now it works when run:

```
kubectl get pods --context=myservice3-context
```

OR

```
curl -k -v -H "Authorization: Bearer <JWT_token> " https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```